# RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH on Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: android

I am trying to use speech recognition on a Samsung Galaxy S phone (as I know the emu doesn't have the intent). The Galaxy S has a 2.1 Android ROM. For some reason I get that the package does not exist on the device, which doesn't make sense because other apps (google maps, voice dialer, etc) are clearly using this.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to work?

The code is more or less the same as google's example (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html).

As a further note, I found this thread which seems to indicate that the srec library is missing randomly on devices:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-discuss/browse_thread/thread/2a53ec01bdff8e67

Is there a way I can do this manually (i.e. contact Google's SOAP API for speech recognition)? Alternatively, can I just copy the srec source code from somewhere and put it directly into my project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not a total expert on this, but I do know the actual recognizer task is performed on remote google servers (the voice feature will be sent out). Speech engine itself requires significant amount of memory and computing power. On the device itself, it is only possible to perform limited grammar tasks (for example, call XXX).

Maybe the device manufactures/operators don't have agreement with google?